# Clean config after porting asmx to WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services, web-config, asmx

I have recently changed an old asmx web service into a WCF web service by adding a .svc using VS 2010, which added the necessary WCF stuff to the web.config. The asmx file has been removed and the service class rewritten.
Now I want to cleanse my config from asmx stuff, but I can't figure out which sections in the web.config that I can remove now.
Is there a list of sections that are asmx-only somewhere?
Or is there a list of sections that are the only things WCF needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a list of the configuration sections that WCF uses, just about everything for your services and clients is located in the **ServiceModel** section. Refer to the [system.serviceModel MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx) for a complete overview. Here's a list of the first level of sub-elements allowed in that section:

```
<behaviors>
<bindings>
<client>
<comContracts>
<commonBehaviors>
<diagnostics>
<extensions>
<protocolMapping>
<routing>
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services> 
<standardEndpoints>
```

Of course there may be a few other web/app config sections on which WCF relies, for example if you have TraceListeners defined, etc.